# Can't Login to App Store, iTunes , Xcode , iClouds on Mac 10.12.5

Tags: macos, itunes, icloud, xcode

On my mac I can't login to App Store, iTunes , Xcode , iClouds. Tried using different Apple id but i keep getting error.

> This action could not be completed. try again

I have also tried using the same id on other machine it works but doesn't work on my mac. I am even able to login with the same id on the browser. How can i fix this?

Comment: The error code used to be -45054 error in the iTunes Store for this breakage when a removal / modification happens to  `/Users/Shared`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After i try to figure out now i found the solution

Open your Terminal and put this command

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared
sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared
```

Fixed it

Comment: The decision to use /Users/Shared for system files / certificate chain always seemed an odd one to me: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204649

Comment: Still not working for me.